# Launcher Auto-hide not working in Ubuntu 15.10

Tags: unity, launcher

It simply is not working. It hides with enabling "atuo-hide" feature in setting>appearance but it doesn't re-appear.

What have I done:
1) Keep moving cursor as to escape out left side of display
2) Multiple clicks on left side
3) Enable and hover over top-left corner
4) Install "Unity Tweak tool" and enable "auto-hide" from there and increase sensitivity to a maximum value
5) Install "Compizconfig-settings-manager" and enable "auto-hide" in Launcher tab and reduce intensity from 20 to 1
5) sudo apt-get upgrade unity
*I do not have multiple display enabled*

Can anyone help?

Thanks,
Anup

Comment: Maybe too simple... but did you try a simple reboot?

Comment: Of course I did a number of times.

Comment: I expected you did but just to be sure...  By the way, if you disable auto-hide the launcher is shown without problems? Or isn't it showing altogether?

Comment: try ccsm / unity plugin / launcher / hide launcher, this is the only thing that worked here after latest 14.04 update at least